# Query based on date range

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have two tables. Table-A filled with transactional data. Table-B being a reference table for rates given a particular week. I would like to get the rate from Table B into Table A based on the Date being within the week outlined in Table B. I tried multiple query techniques and all fell flat on their face. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Table B
Start_Date  End_Date    Rate
12/30/2013  1/5/2014    $1.20 
1/6/2014    1/12/2014   $1.25 
1/13/2014   1/19/2014   $2.22 
1/20/2014   1/26/2014   $2.23 
1/27/2014   2/2/2014    $2.11 


Table A
ID  Date      Rate
1   1/1/2014    
2   1/11/2014   
3   1/21/2014   
4   1/10/2014   
5   1/15/2014   
6   1/22/2014   
7   1/20/2014   
8   1/3/2014    
9   1/2/2014    
10  1/4/2014
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: How did something start at the end of 2014 and end at the beginning of 2014?

Comment: I can't give real data due to confidentiality. So its sample data...fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE A, B SET A.Rate = [B].[Rate]
WHERE (([A].[DT] Between [B].[StartDate] And [B].[EndDate]));
```

I changed `A.Date` to `A.DT` because `Date` is a reserved word in Access.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select b.rate from a,b where a.date <= b.end_date and a.date >= b.start.date
```

OR

```
select b.rate from a,b where a.date between b.start_date and  b.end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.  First off, I'm presuming that your first date there in B is actually 12/30/13.

Then, date is a reserved word, so it's not a good column name in table A.  I've renamed it DateA in my example.

Finally, here's a query that returns the rate for that date.  It doesn't update table A, but it should give you what you need to do so:

```
SELECT [Table B].Rate, [Table A].DateA
FROM [Table A], [Table B]
WHERE ((([Table A].DateA) Between [start_date] And [end_date]));
```

Comment: To make this actually update, if you're in Access, change the query type to update, and remove DateA from the select list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I entered this into a query and changed it to Update. I got an error stating "Cannot execute a select query"

Comment: That copy paste above is from SQL View.  If you paste it in, and then change back to design view, you should be able to change the type to update, and then place what you want in the "Update to" field.

See Overmind's comment as well, for the programmatic (SQL View) input.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered doing this through code?  My Access lingo is a bit rusty, but I believe it would be called "Opening Dataset" based on table A ("cursor" in Transact-SQL).  Then you can loop through it and do SQL search for each row.

Comment: This is not difficult to perform in SQL. If you are "rusty" you should not be submitting an answer to a question. Answers must be clear-cut and definitive, and something the OP can run with. Not hunches and guesses. Relativity is also important - Where do you see anything about `tSQL`?

Comment: This is neither a hunch nor a guess. I worked in Access for 4 years and was MS certified.  I did not say you could not run SQL, just that going with the stored procedure might prove more effective.  To clarify - run faster and take up fewer resources, depending on the amount of processed data.

Comment: "SELECT A,B" with no key will leave you with the Cartesian product of the two queries, never the most effective solutio

Comment: I meant it as constructive criticism.